# How to convert column to numeric with errors due to 'invisible' character

Tags: python, pandas, replace, type-conversion

I have a DF imported by pd.read_html. This column is an object.
It looks like that - very simple right?

```
Column
6 600
7 000
6 700
```

What I'm trying to do is to:
Convert it to numeric
I receive an error 'Unable to parse string "6 600" at position 0'
That's why I decided to remove a space character ' '  to prepare it for conversion to a numeric column.

What I've tried:

```
df['Column'] = df['Column'].str.replace(' ','', regex = True) 
#==> Nothing changes, it stays like it was. And I still can't move it to numeric.
```

I've tried as well:

```
df['Column'] = df['Column'].map(lambda x:x.split(' ')[0])
#==> The same outcome like above
```

When I try to convert it to a numeric I receive such error:

```
df['Column'] = df['Column'].astype({'Column': 'int'})
#==> invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6\xa0600'
```

and when I do this...

```
df['Column'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Column'])
#==> Unable to parse string "6 600" at position 0
```

As I understand it has to be connected with types and obviously I do something wrong, but I can't get what it is. What is interesting in the first-mentioned method (str.replace) was OK for other data that I imported.

Anyone can help me to solve it?

Comment: 0xa0 (a.k.a U+00A0) is a non-breaking space. You could either select it specifically or use a regex to filter out everything that looks like whitespace (using `\s`).

Comment: ``df.Column.str.split().str.join("").astype(int)`` ?

Comment: @Sushanth thanks! That works perfectly. Nevertheless, I'd need to think a bit more about why it works!

Comment: The one that you shared `df['Column'] = df['Column'].str.replace(' ','', regex = True)` works perfectly for me for your dataframe!

Comment: @Norrius thanks for pointing out a 'regex' - I'm going to read more about it as a must!

Comment: @FaridJafri I think it works perfectly because you probably created the DF by yourself. My DF was imported from web by 'pd.read_html'. So it consists of HTML. That's my understanding of why it doesn't work.